# Text of Sri Bhuvaneshwari Ashtakam

Tags: devi, bhuvaneshwari

I have heard the audio of Sri Bhuvaneshwati Ashtakam here https://youtu.be/IzzZOwqAL1k but didn't find text version of it.

Can someone point me the text (English transliteration if possible) of Sri Bhuvaneshwari Ashtakam?

Comment: Thank You. I think transliterations are very important for this site, much more helping to discover Sanskrit.

Comment: @Lucky Transliteration questions are off-topic but if you are looking for text of Bhuvaneshwari Ashtakam, it would be on-topic.

Comment: If yo already have text and looking for Transliteration, then question should be closed (bounty will be refunded). But if you're looking for text then revise the question

Comment: Thank You for the answers. If someone will have the text btw of the Bhuvaneshwari Ashtakam , since i still searching, i will be happy to share the bounty

Comment: @LuckyPashu I have just edited your question. Check it.

Comment: @Pandya , Ok thank you!

Comment: @LuckyPashu See this https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=a7qXnS1HGIo with only the lyrics.

Comment: @sv. thank you. You know honestly I’m a little skeptical on this - firstly because though being termed as an Ashtakam, it has more than 8 verses, secondly the source and composer seem to be unknown and lastly because it’s near impossible to find barring one tamil version and this YouTube video. When you type Bhuvaneshwari Ashtakam, there’s one from the Rudrayamale which comes as a dialogue between Shiva Parvati. What are your views?

Comment: @sv. Also, not being sure of the authenticity, will it be appropriate to make an answer out of it? As in luckypashu and anyone else can refer the Tamil version or the YouTube video from the comments and the authenticity will also remain intact. Reputation isn’t important at all, sanctity of the site is more important. Please guide.

Comment: If possible a transliteration as a side text would be best

Comment: @sv. okay. I found another 2-3 tamil sources Which I’m including as a link in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the lyrics of the Bhuvaneshwari Ashtakam in Devanagari alongwith the English transliteration:

> ##### श्री भुवनेश्वर्यष्टकं
>   Śrī Bhuvanēśvaryaṣṭakaṁ
>
> अञ्जन रञ्जित खञ्जन मञ्जुल लोचन लोकन पूर्णदये 
>  कुञ्जर चर्म
> कुटुम्बिनि काञ्चन नूपुर शोभित पादयुगे। 
>  सञ्चित पापविनाशिनि कुञ्जर
> भद्र सुतेऽम्बुज तुल्यपदे 
>  पालय मां भुवनेश्वरि पालक मानत माधृत
> भक्तजने ॥ १ ॥
>
> añjana rañjita khañjana mañjula lōcana lōkana pūrṇadayē 
>  kuñjara
> carma kuṭumbini kāñcana nūpura śōbhita pādayugē। 
>  sañcita
> pāpavināśini kuñjara bhadra sutē'mbuja tulyapadē 
>  pālaya māṁ
> bhuvanēśvari pālaka mānata mādhr̥ta bhaktajanē ॥ 1 ॥
>
> मत्त महासुर पत्तन दाहक नृत्तपतिप्रिय रूपयुते 
>  सत्तव मानव मानस
> चिन्तित सुन्दर पादयुगे सुभगे। 
>  ध्वस्त *हलासुर* हस्त गताङ्कुश
> शोभिनि मत्त मरालगते 
>  शङ्करि मे भुवनेश्वरि शङ्कुरु शङ्ख समानगले
> विमले ॥ २ ॥
>
> matta mahāsura pattana dāhaka nr̥ttapatipriya rūpayutē 
>  sattava
> mānava mānasa cintita sundara pādayugē subhagē। 
>  dhvasta
> *halāsura* hasta gatāṅkuśa śōbhini matta marālagatē 
>  śaṅkari mē bhuvanēśvari śaṅkuru śaṅkha samānagalē vimalē ॥ 2 ॥
>
> अम्बुरुहासन सन्नुत वैभव शालिनि शूलिनि शैलसूते 
>  तुम्बुरु नारद
> गीतगुणे मणि मण्डित मण्डप मध्यगते। 
>  अम्ब कदम्ब वनावसतेऽम्बुज शोभि
> रमा विनुते विनते 
>  शाम्भवि मां भुवनेश्वरि पालय कालभयाद्दयया
> सहिते ॥ ३ ॥
>
> amburuhāsana sannuta vaibhava śālini śūlini śailasūtē 
>  tumburu
> nārada gītaguṇē maṇi maṇḍita maṇḍapa madhyagatē। 
>  amba kadamba
> vanāvasatē'mbuja śōbhi ramā vinutē vinatē 
>  śāmbhavi māṁ
> bhuvanēśvari pālaya kālabhayāddayayā sahitē ॥ 3 ॥
>
> आसुरशक्तिहरेऽमित भासुर भूषण भास्वर कायधरे 
>  भूसुर वैदिक मन्त्र
> नुते गरु धूप सुगन्धित चारु कचे। 
>  दारुण संसृति मोह विदारिणि
> भीरुजनाभयदे वरदे 
>  मा तरु मे भुवनेश्वरि दूरय दुष्कृतमाशु महेश्वरि
> मे ॥ ४ ॥
>
> āsuraśaktiharē'mita bhāsura bhūṣaṇa bhāsvara kāyadharē 
>  bhūsura
> vaidika mantra nutē garu dhūpa sugandhita cāru kacē। 
>  dāruṇa
> saṁsr̥ti mōha vidāriṇi bhīrujanābhayadē varadē 
>  mā taru mē
> bhuvanēśvari dūraya duṣkr̥tamāśu mahēśvari mē ॥ 4 ॥
>
> सोमधरे कमनीयमुखे नमनीयपदे समनीतिधरे 
>  सामनुते वर नाम
> युतेऽमितभामहिते रिपु भीम गुणे। 
>  तामरसोपम पाणि धृतोत्तम चामर वीजन
> लोलसुरे 
>  मामव हे भुवनेश्वरि कामवशङ्गत मानसमङ्घ्रिनतम् ॥ ५ ॥
>
> sōmadharē kamanīyamukhē namanīyapadē samanītidharē 
>  sāmanutē vara
> nāma yutē'mitabhāmahitē ripu bhīma guṇē। 
>  tāmarasōpama pāṇi
> dhr̥tōttama cāmara vījana lōlasurē 
>  māmava hē bhuvanēśvari
> kāmavaśaṅgata mānasamaṅghrinatam ॥ 5 ॥
>
> कालि कपालिनि शूलिनि शूलि मनोहर कामिनि शैलसूते 
>  पालित भक्तजनेलि
> विमोहक धूलि धराम्बुज शोभिपते। 
>  व्रीलित मन्मथ सुन्दरि चालित चामर
> शोभित पार्श्वयुगे 
> *तूलित वैरि भले* परिपालय मां भुवनेश्वरि लोलमतिम् ॥ ६ ॥
>
> kāli kapālini śūlini śūli manōhara kāmini śailasūtē 
>  pālita
> bhaktajanēli vimōhaka dhūli dharāmbuja śōbhipatē। 
>  vrīlita
> manmatha sundari cālita cāmara śōbhita pārśvayugē 
> *tūlita vairi bhalē* paripālaya māṁ bhuvanēśvari lōlamatim ॥ 6 ॥
>
> भस्मित मन्मथ शङ्कर विस्मय कारक सुस्मित शोभमुखे 
>  पल्लव कोमलपङ्कज
> तल्लज पाणितले कल भाषिणि माम्। 
>  उद्धर सत्वरमध्वर तोषिणि वाग्वर
> देवगुरु प्रणते 
>  नूतन सालपुरी निलये भुवनेश्वरि पालय दासमिमम् ॥ ७ ॥
>
> bhasmita manmatha śaṅkara vismaya kāraka susmita śōbhamukhē 
> pallava kōmalapaṅkaja tallaja pāṇitalē kala bhāṣiṇi mām। 
>  uddhara
> satvaramadhvara tōṣiṇi vāgvara dēvaguru praṇatē 
>  nūtana sālapurī
> nilayē bhuvanēśvari pālaya dāsamimam ॥ 7 ॥
>
> भक्तियुतोत्तम भुक्ति विधायिनि शक्तिधरात्मज शक्तियुते 
> शुद्धियुतानघ बुद्धि विवर्द्धिनि देवधुनीधर पार्श्वगते। 
>  चक्र
> *समर्चक शक्र मुखामर* वक्र विरोधि विनाशिनि ते 
>  नाद मयाकृति *शोभित* मे भुवनेश्वरि पातु पदाब्जयुगम् ॥ ८ ॥
>
> bhaktiyutōttama bhukti vidhāyini śaktidharātmaja śaktiyutē 
> śuddhiyutānagha buddhi vivarddhini dēvadhunīdhara pārśvagatē। 
> cakra samarcaka śakra mukhāmara vakra virōdhi vināśini tē 
>  nāda
> mayākr̥ti *śōbhita* mē bhuvanēśvari pātu padābjayugam ॥ 8 ॥
>
> *शिष्टनदाखिल* विष्टपमातृ *वराष्टककृष्ट मतिं मतिमान्* 
>  पुष्टतनोऽधिक हृष्ट मनाबहु तुष्ट *जनेष्ट करो* विलसेत्। 
> *धृष्टदरान्तक* कष्टद पाशविसृष्ट भयस् सुखितो मनुजो 
> *दिष्ट विदिष्ट सुकोष्ठ* दिशासु भवेत् प्रथितो महितस्सकलैः ॥ ९ ॥
>
> *śiṣṭanadākhila* viṣṭapamātr̥ *varāṣṭakakr̥ṣṭa matiṁ matimān*
>  puṣṭatanō'dhika hr̥ṣṭa manābahu tuṣṭa *janēṣṭa karō* vilasēt। 
> *dhr̥ṣṭadarāntaka* kaṣṭada pāśavisr̥ṣṭa bhayas sukhitō manujō 
> *diṣṭa vidiṣṭa sukōṣṭha* diśāsu bhavēt prathitō mahitassakalaiḥ ॥ 9 ॥
>
> ॥ इति श्री भुवनेश्वर्यष्टकं सम्पूर्णम् ॥ 
>  ॥ iti śrī
> bhuvanēśvaryaṣṭakaṁ sampūrṇam ॥

*(Note:- the entire Ashtakam is more or less translatable easily except the parts in italics (98% in the last two verses) out of which no sense can be made. If someone finds the correct words with meanings, kindly update the answer)*

[Source 1](http://aanmeegamsolkirathu.blogspot.com/2011/06/blog-post_7752.html)
[Source 2](https://m.facebook.com/2086518161589959/photos/-%E0%AE%B8%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%80_%E0%AE%AA%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%A9%E0%AF%87%E0%AE%B8%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%B0%E0%AE%BF_%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%B7%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9F%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%9E%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9C%E0%AE%A9-%E0%AE%B0%E0%AE%9E%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9A%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%A4-%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%9E%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9C%E0%AE%A9-%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%9E%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9C%E0%AF%82%E0%AE%B3-%E0%AE%B2%E0%AF%8B%E0%AE%9A%E0%AE%A9-%E0%AE%B2%E0%AF%8B%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%A9-%E0%AE%AA%E0%AF%82%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%A3%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%AF%E0%AF%87%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%9E%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9C%E0%AE%B0-%E0%AE%9A%E0%AE%B0%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%AE-/2108323182742790/) - almost same as Source 1
[Source 3](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=a7qXnS1HGIo) - video not recommended as it has countless mistakes.

EDIT:- Adding translation for a few lines (parts which have not been able to be translated by me are in brackets with a question mark. If anyone is able to please feel free to edit)

> ##### English Translation
>
> > The one having her beautiful eyes, coloured with collyrium and who
> > looks with complete kindness
> >  Wife of Shiva (wearing elephant
> > skin), with golden anklets adorning both feet,
> >  Destroyer of
> > accumulated sins, (kuñjara bhadra sutē?), having lotus like feet,
> > Keep me/nurture me oh Bhuvaneshwari (pālaka ... bhaktajanē= devotees
> > who are bent and dependent?) ॥ 1 ॥
>
> > Beloved of the one who burnt the city of the intoxicated mahasura (I
> > don’t know what this is, though in the Shiva Tandava, Shiva has been
> > called Makhāntaka) and the Lord of dance (Shiva), having a beautiful
> > form 
> >  (sattava?), one whose both feet are contemplated by
> > people’s minds, beautiful one
> >  (Destroyed halasura?), having a
> > goad adorning her hand, (matta maralagata?)
> >  Oh Shankari, oh
> > Bhuvaneshwari give me auspiciousness, (śaṅkha samānagalē?), oh pure
> > one ॥ 2 ॥
>
> > Having a lotus as her seat praised, one with great opulence, one with
> > a trident (śūlam), daughter of the mountain (Himavan) 
> >  Attribute
> > of the songs of Tumburu gandharva and Nārada, one who sits in an
> > assembly decked with jewels
> >  Mother, dweller of Kadambavana,
> > (worshipped and bowed down to by Lakshmi?)
> >  Oh Shambhavi (wife of
> > Shambhu Shiva), oh Bhuvaneshwari nurture/protect me with compassion
> > from the fear of death ॥ 3 ॥
>
> > Repeller of demonic forces, one wearing immeasurably shining jewellery
> > on her glowing body 
> >  One praised by the gods and Vedic mantras,
> > one with the aroma of the Aguru incense in her hair 
> >  Destroyer of
> > the terrible delusion of creation (the world), one who makes scared
> > people fearless and giver of boons 
> >  (mā taru?) Oh Bhuvaneshwari,
> > oh Maheshwari make my bad deeds go away quickly ॥ 4 ॥
>
> > The one who bears the moon, oh attractive faced one, one who’s feet
> > are worshipped and bearer of equality/justice 
> >  One Praised in
> > songs, (vara nāma yutē?), one whose immeasurable lustre is
> > (worshipped?) and one with fearsome attributes to her enemies 
> > One holding a lotus in her hand and being fanned by the gods 
> > Protect me oh Bhuvaneshwari, I bow down to your feet with my mind
> > which is under the influence of lust ॥ 5 ॥
>
> > Oh Kali, wielder of skulls, having a trident, one lovingly enticing
> > Shiva, daughter of the mountain (Himavan)
> >  (Protected devotees,
> > vimōhaka dhūli dharāmbuja śōbhipatē?)
> >   One with such beauty that
> > shamed Manmatha (Kamadeva), one with moving fans adorning both her
> > sides
> >  (tūlita vairi bhalē?) protect/ nurture me, with a moving
> > (everchanging, confused) mind, Oh Bhuvaneshwari ॥ 6 ॥
>
> > (Manmatha who was turned to ashes, causing wonderment Shiva?,) one
> > with a beautiful smile adorning her face
> >  One with palms soft like
> > the most excellent lotus, sweet talking goddesss 
> >  Uplift me, Oh
> > the one who satiates sacrifices quickly and is praised by Brihaspati,
> > guru of the devatas
> >  (nūtana sālapurī nilayē?), Oh Bhuvaneshwari
> > protect this Servant (me) ॥ 7 ॥
>
> > One coupled with devotion, establisher of excellent (bhukti = food?
> > Annapurna?), having the wielder of the shakti, Skanda as her son,
> > coupled with strength,
> >  One coupled with purity, one who increases
> > sinless intellect, one who sits beside Shiva, the bearer of the Ganges
> >
> >  (Chakra samarcaka ... śobhita?) protect me, Oh Bhuvaneshwari,
> > one with both lotus like feet ॥ 8 ॥
>
> > (śiṣṭanadā?), mother of the entire world, (varāṣṭakakr̥ṣṭa matiṁ
> > matimān?)
> >  (May she abide with people with a nourished body, a
> > great healthy mind, greatly satisfied people and people who perform
> > auspicious deeds?)
> >  (dhr̥ṣṭadarāntaka?) fear arising from the
> > pain-afflicting noose,  (diṣṭa vidiṣṭa sukōṣṭha?) in all directions
> > (may her greatness?) be spread by everyone ॥ 9 ॥

Comment: Thank You, that’s what i was looking for! 

Comment: If you can add also the translation of the Devanagari text will be awesome!

Comment: @LuckyPashu yes sure, but it won’t be 100% proper and few words and the last two verses might not get translated. It’ll be missing quite a few things here and there. Is that fine?

Comment: yes it will be useful to understand the general meaning and easier for amateur translators in Devanagari as well ! Thank You, i will give the bounty.

Comment: @LuckyPashu done. Check if it’s okay :)

Comment: excellent now looks complete

Comment: @LuckyPashu thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
||Om shrI bhuvnEshvariyai namaH ||
||shrI bhuvanEshvari aShTakam ||

Om 

aMjana raMjita khaMjana maMjula 
lOcana lOkana pUrNa dayE 
kuMjara carma kuTuMbhini kAMcana 
nUpura shObhita pAdayugE|

saMcita pApa vinAshini kuMjara 
bhadra sutEMbhuja tulya padE 
pAlayamAm bhuvanEshvari pAlaka 
mAnata mAdhRuta bhaktajani||1||

matta mahAsura pattana dAraka 
dRutta vati priya rUpayutE 
sattava mAnava mAnasa ciMtita 
suMdara pAdayugE shubhagE|

dvastha daLAsura hasta gatAMkusha 
shObhini mattama rAdagatE 
shaMkari mE bhuvanEshvari shaMkuru 
shaMka samAnaga lE vimalE||2||

aMburu hAsana sannuta vaibhava 
shAlini shUlini shailasutE 
tuMburu nArada gIta guNi maNi 
maMDita maMdapa madhyagatE|

aMba kadaMba vanAvasa tEMbhuja 
shObhi ramAvidu dEvinatE 
shAMbhavi mAm bhuvanEshvari pAlaya 
kAlabhayAr daya yA sahitE||3||

hAsura shakti harE mita bhAsura 
bhUShaNa bhAsvara gAyadharE 
bhUsura vaidika maMtranutE guru 
dhUpa sugaMdita cAru kacE|

dAruNa saMshriti mOha vidhAriNi 
bhIru janAbhaya dEvaradE 
mAtaru mE bhuvanEshvari dUraya 
duShkRuta mAsu mahEshvarI mE||4||

sOmadharE kamanIya mukhE 
namaNIya padE samanIti dharE 
sAmanu tEva nAmayutE mita 
bhAmahitE ripu bhImaguNE|

tAmara sOpama pANi dRutOttama 
cAmara vIcana lOlasurE 
mAm mavahE bhuvanEshvari kAmava 
shaMkata mAnasa maMdri natam||5||

kAlika pAlini shUlini shUli 
manOhara kAmini shailasutE
pAlita bhakta janEli vimOhaka 
dhULi dharAMbhuja shObhivatE|

drIlita manmadha suMdari cAlita 
cAmara shObhita pAshvayugE 
tUlita vairi bhalE paripAlaya mAm 
bhuvanEshvari lOla matim||6||

bhasmita manmadha shaMkara vismaya 
kAraka susmita shObhi mukhE 
pallava kOmala paMkaja tallaja 
pANi talE kala bhAShiNi mAm|

uddara satvara madhvara dOShiNi 
vAgvara dEva guru praNatE 
nUtana sAlapurI nilayE bhuvanEshvari 
pAlaya dAsamimam||7||

bhakti yutOttama bhukti vidhAyini 
shakti dharAtmaja shaktiyutE 
shuddhi yutAnaka buddhi vivardhini 
dEva tunIdhara pAsvagatE|

cakra samarcaka shatra mukhAmara 
vakra virOdhi vinAshinitE 
nAda mayAkRuti shObhini mE 
bhuvanEshvari bhAtu padAbja yugam||8||

shiShTana dAkhila viShTapa mAtRu 
varAShTaka kriShTam tin matimAm 
puShTa danOdita kRuShTa manA bahu 
duShTa janEShTa karO vilasE|

dRuShTa tarAMtaka kaShTada pAsha 
vishriShTa bhaya sukhitO manujO 
diShTa vidhiShTa subhOShTa dishA shubhavE 
pratitO mahi tasya kalai||9||
Om shrI bhuvanEshvariyai namaH 
Om shrI bhuvanEshvariyai namaH 
Om shrI bhuvanEshvariyai namaH 
||iti shrI bhuvanEshvari aShTakam saMpUrNam||
||shubhamastu||
```

Comment: Thank You, that’s what i was looking for! 